# Refresh Android webview after closing external page

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, webview

Im using Android webview to load a website. And for some reasons I wanted to show some external URL off the webview. That is, when user click on a link ( link is in the webview ) a new page will open in the default web browser. This part is working.

Now I wanted to refresh the webview after user close this external page running outside webview.

This can be done, If we running both pages ( parent and external page ) running in browser. Following code is working for this scenario

```
    $('#closeButton').click(function () {
        window.opener.location.reload();
        window.close();
    });
```

Above "window.opener.location.reload()" is not reloading Android webview.

Is there are any solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

You may know but the only solution is : `mWebView.reload();` for android